# Using a separated source folder from SVN on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

So, here in the company we work with svn, and our svn server only have the source folder. When I use NetBeans, it's everything ok because I can add source folders in project and will work fine in svn. But on eclipse if i do the checkout from command line and add that folder in my dynamic web project, I can't see the svn history and nothing, svnclipse just does not work on that folder. 
Our structure of the projects it's something like this

```
Workspace
     Project folder
          Project1
             Project configuration files
          SourceCode
             Packages
     Project folder 2
          Project2
          SourceCode
```

I already try to make checkout using svnclipse, but he add alot of extra config files, he turns the folder in a project and the source folder is add as a link to another project, in this scenario the svnclipse quick diff does not work properly.

There is a way to use that folder as source and Svnclipse works on that ?

Sorry if my English is not so good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do what you want. In Eclipse a source control provider can only be connected to the project itself.  So options are:

1. Use another svn client like command line or TortoiseSVN.
2. Create a small SVN project with the Eclipse project configuration files that also use svn:externals to pull in your source folder from repository.

With option 2, you would checkout this small SVN project from some other repository using Subclipse in Eclipse, could even be a local file:// repository and then the  svn:externals property would also cause your source folder to be checked out.

Comment: sorry for the late response, in the long term i get used to not have quick diff working properly when add external source folders on my main project. I'm gonna try this again. Thanks